# Is injectivity or surjectivity enough to show countability?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm new into Measure theory and I'm self-taught. For some time now, I have been encountering proofs that showed countability using injectivity or surjectivity. Here are examples https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Countable_Union_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable/Proof_1 and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Countable_Union_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable/Proof_2

To me, a set is countable if and only if there exists a one-one correspondence or bijection between it and the set of natural numbers, $\Bbb{N}.$

**MY QUESTION**

Is injectivity or surjectivity enough to show countability as the above proofs have done?

Comment: Your definition would refer to *countably infinite*

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: Countably infinite? Let me check!

Comment: I think both are required as indicated by [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)

Comment: From what I have gathered, a set is countable if and only if there exists a bijection between it and the set of natural numbers, $\Bbb{N}.$ From this source https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Countable_Set/Definition_1, injection is needed. From this one, https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Countable_Set/Definition_2, a set is countable if and only if it is finite or countably infinite and from here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Countable_Set/Definition_3; a set is countable if and only if there exists a bijection between it and a subset of $\Bbb{N}$. So, which one do I follow?

Comment: This question has set a confusion to me for some time now. I don't know how to explain it when the time comes. It's an honest question. So, I think it deserves to be closed!

Comment: These are all equivalent definitions. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual definitions are that:

1. a set is finite if it is in bijection with $\{1 , 2, \cdots, n\}$ for some $n$
2. a set is countably infinite if it is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$
3. a set is countable if it is finite or countably infinite

Then, the following conditions are equivalent for a set $S$:

1. $S$ is countable
2. There is a surjection $\mathbb{N} \to S$
3. There is an injection $S \to \mathbb{N}$

Comment: If there is a surjection from a countable set to S (apart from N) or an injection from S to a countable set, then is it true that S is countable?